# For tomato allergies, finding/shipping Seviocard and other European cultivars to the US

Tags: tomatoes, seeds

I have a tomato allergy and so am looking for a specific cultivar, Seviocard (hybrid), which is known to be low in the allergen.  It's not available at any USA seeds supplier that we can find. There are a select few European websites which ship it, but cannot find one that ships to the United States.  these websites also seem to charge a very high amount, around $100 USD, for just a few hundred seeds,  to ship to people within their own country.

- does anyone know why this is only available in Europe?  is it just this cultivar or is this a common thing?
- why is it so expensive for Europeans to buy this seed?

  other cultivars:

  - Rugantino
  - Rhianna
  - Orama
  - Messina

Comment: I just found an offer of 200 Euro for 1000 seeds. One thousand. Know how much produce that would yield? This is for professional farmers.

Comment: This variety seems not to be available for home gardeners right now. Maybe because it is impractical to grow for homegardeners.

Comment: It is either a (traditional) quarantine issue or a new variety that makes the price so high

Comment: Those  are some good theories.  what would an example of "Impractical" be specifically? Also last year around summer/fall, I looked for either Seviocard or Rugantino (can't remember) and also could not find it. How new would "new" be?

Comment: Please remember to ping people with @. With impractical, i would mean a heated greenhouse, which was mentioned somewhere for Seviocard.